# Remover acentos de um array

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um select no qual é preenchido através de uma consulta no banco:

```
<select class="form-control" name="select_cidades">
                <option>Selecione a Cidade</option>
                <?php

                $result_cidades = "SELECT * FROM cidades";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cidades);
                while($row_cidades = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_cidades['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row_cidades['nome']; ?>
                    </option>

                    <?php
                }

                ?>
            </select>
```

O problema é que as cidades que tem acentos estão aparecendo simbolo de ?
Não consegui encontrar nenhuma função que limpe acentos em um array.
Alguém tem alguma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma função que utilizo:

```
function removerAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/",
    "/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/",
    "/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),
    explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
}
```

E no seu código você pode fazer algo como:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_cidades['id']; ?>"> <?php echo removerAcentos($row_cidades['nome']);
```

Mas o ideal é você verificar a codificação do seu HTML, ao invés de tirar os acentos tente utilizar esta função:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_cidades['id']; ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($row_cidades['nome']);
```

Documentação: [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8-encode)

Comment: Deu certo a segunda. Não sabia que tinha que utilizar o encode no php, pra min só declarar no html já funcionava acentuação ahahh obrigada!